# How to fetch the value from comma separated attribute in sql?

Tags: sql, asp.net

Here is my table called Employee.I want name of Employee whose active is 1 and who know the java.
I am working on sql server 2000.Split function does not work in sql 2000?What is alternative.How to handle this?

```
id  name    lname   Active  Skill
1   Sonia   Mohite  1       C,C#,JAVA,.NET
2   Dilip   Kale    1       JAVA
3   Kalpesh More    0       C,C#,JAVA
4   Monika  Naik    1       C
```

Thanks all of u for ur help.But I have another table callled student.I want name of student whose 
isactive is 1 and who have subjectcode 1.Like does not work here.It gave name of employee who have subject code 11 or 12 also.

```
id  name    Isactive    subjectcode
1   Shilpa  1           1,2,3
2   Manasi  1           11
3   kamal   1           12,3
4   Hans    0           1,2
5   Rupali  1          1,11,12
```

Comment: Why don't you have a table `Skill` and another `UserSkill`(foreign-keys to `Employee` and `Skill`)?

Comment: It is already created.I can't change.

Comment: But you should change it if it's important. Otherwise this model is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LIKE` .

### Query

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE active=1 
AND skill LIKE '%Java%';
```

Comment: And if I Like C (not C#)?

Comment: Thanks for ur help.I have another table.Like does not work there.I have modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ACTIVE = 1
AND ',' || SKILL || ',' LIKE '%,JAVA,%';
```

Note: Above is for oracle which supports || for concatenation. For other DBs, you may have to use CONCAT like below:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ACTIVE = 1
WHERE CONCAT (",",  (CONCAT (SKILL, ",") ) LIKE '%,JAVA,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Query

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE active=1 
AND Contains(skill, "Java")>0;
```

Comment: With "JAVA" in upper case?

Comment: That depends on how it is stored in your database.

Answer (score 0):

### Query

```
SELECT * FROM employee
WHERE active=6
AND skill LIKE
```